# Samsung TV "Mode not supported"

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I have a [**Samsung SyncMaster 932MW LCD TV**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJGwv.jpg) from **2008**, which I connected to my **Asus VivoBook S** with **Windows 10 build 1903** via HDMI as a secondary monitor.

Even though I have set the resolution to 1440 x 900 and 60Hz ([I also tried others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR4yW.png)), the TV displays the error message [`"Mode not supported"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg9Jl.jpg).

However the TV is recognized by the PC, but it doesn't show anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have the option for lower refresh rates?

Comment: @Moab Nope, only 60 and 75 Hz

Comment: I suggest starting at 640x480 and working your way up

Comment: @Moab I tried that resolution with GTF, CVT and CVT-RB with different refresh rates, but no one works :(( I am using Intel control panel. Should I add an ["advanced" resoluton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHAGE.jpg)?

Comment: @Moab OMG now it works with **640x480, 16,8M colors and 59Hz**, the lowest resolution. I tried [others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMQdu.png) but I understood that that one is the only one that supports 59Hz and the TV runs at that frequency. So how can I get more resolution? Also from intel control panel seems to change nothing since I set it to the only resolution above and it doesnt work. Maybe there's a conflict between windows and intel settings.

Comment: @Moab Do you know if I can higher the resolution?